# Adding new row using update_batch()

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, codeigniter-3

in my DATABASE table

```
    parent_id | sibling_id | name | age
    1         | 1          | john | 4
    1         | 2          | rose | 7
```

in my AngularJS controller, i concatenated a data that looks like this:

```
 $data = array( 
    '0' => 
    ( 'parent_id' => 1,
      'sibling_id ' => 1,
      'name ' => "john",
      'age' => 4),
    '1' => 
    ( 'parent_id' => 1,
      'sibling_id ' => 2,
      'name ' => "rose",
      'age' => 7),
    '2' => 
    ( 'parent_id' => 1,
      'sibling_id ' => 3,
      'name ' => "mae",
      'age' => 5),
```

i added another array (mae details) to the data, and when i passed it to codeigniter model,
the batch_update() seems not working in terms of adding new row. Batch_update() seems only to work if you have an update to the original rows. Because my code only works for the original rows not whenever i added new row.

I think what i lack here is the logic only.

Comment: how you are adding new row?

Comment: In my angularjs, i saved the data from the database in an array, (i.e. $scope.items = [];) and then i add rows to it using array.push() function in angularjs. Now i am sending this data from angularjs to CI controller thru $http() POST.

Comment: I think you're looking for `replace`, not `update`.